# Firefox Extension "setBadgeText" not working

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to make an extension that displays a BadgeText (like Adblock). If I write this line `document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";` in my JS file it works. The red border gets added to each website.

Now I wanted to do `browser.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: "Hello world!"});`

But it does nothing.

Here is my manifest:

```
{

"description": "Shows the amount of cookies on a website",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "XXXXXX Cookies",
"permissions": ["cookies","<all_urls>","activeTab", "storage", "browsingData","contextualIdentities", "privacy", "notifications"],
"version": "1.0",
"homepage_url": "https://XXXXX.com",

"browser_action": {
"browser_style": true,
"default_title": "XXXXXX Cookie Manager",
"default_icon": {
  "48": "icons/icon48.png",
  "96": "icons/icon96.png"
}
},

"icons": {
"48": "icons/icon48.png",
"96": "icons/icon96.png"
},

"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["my.js"]
}
]

}
```

Maybe the problem lies in the syntax of my js file. I just wrote the lines without a function or anything. I'm completely new to js.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`browserAction` API is not available in content script. You must send a message to the background script and set it from the background script.

Additionally, `browserAction.setBadgeText` maximum character is 4 so it will only show `Hell`